# Table with cells of different widths

Tags: tables, columns, width

I'm trying to typeset a Word doc in LaTeX - mainly so that I can get the results I want, rather than Word (or LibreOffice) making my decisions for me.  And my current difficulty consists of a few tables.  One has cells with different widths in its rows:

```
-----------
|  |      |
-----------
|      |  |
-----------
|      |  |
-----------
|  |      |
-----------
```

I can get this effect with lots of multicolumns, or by doing it with TiKZ, but I would have thought there'd be an easier way.  In fact, one table I have is perfectly regular, except for one cell which is divided in two, like in this second row:

```
-------------
|   |       |
-------------
|   |   |   |
-------------
|   |       |
-------------
|   |       |
-------------
```

What's the best way: tabular (or one of its variants) with multicolumn, TiKZ, or something else?

Answer (score 3):

This approach places a faux column divider where you want, using `\vlyn` (which adds `\tabcolsep` gap around a `\vline`).  Using a judicious combination of actual columns and faux columns, you should be able to achieve your aim.

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\vlyn{%
  \hspace{\tabcolsep}%
  \vline%
  \hspace{\tabcolsep}%
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{|c|}
\hline
a\vlyn bcd\\
\hline
abc\vlyn d\\
\hline
abc\vlyn d\\
\hline
a\vlyn bcd\\
\hline
\end{tabular}

\begin{tabular}{|c|c|}
\hline
a& bcd\\
\hline
a& bcd\\
\hline
a& bc\vlyn d\\
\hline
a& bcd\\
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh I'd completely forgotten all about `\vline` - that's great!  Can you split a cell (using `\vline`) into small cells of specified widths?

Comment: @Alasdair I renamed it `\vlyn` (it was my own macro), so as not to destroy TeX's own `\vline`, and so that I could automatically add `\tabcolsep` gap around it.  See revision.

Comment: @Alasdair  For sub-columns of specified width, I would put the text into a `\makebox` of the specified width.  In such cases, you may have to omit the additional `\tabcolsep` gap by using `\vline` directly, rather than `\vlyn`.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to create you tables using the cals tables. Although the variable number and size of columns is not supported, with hacks it works:

[image: variable number of columns]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{cals}
\begin{document}
\makeatletter
\def\cals@framers@width{.4pt}

Table 1\par\smallskip
\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{1cm}{2cm}}
\brow \cell{a} \cell{bcd} \erow
\colwidths{{2cm}{1cm}}
\brow \cell{abc} \cell{d} \erow
\brow \cell{abc} \cell{d} \erow
\colwidths{{1cm}{2cm}}
\brow  \cell{a} \cell{bcd} \erow
\end{calstable}

\bigskip

Table 2\par\smallskip
\begin{calstable}
\colwidths{{1cm}{2cm}}
\brow \cell{a} \cell{bcd} \erow
\brow \cell{a} \cell{bcd} \erow
\colwidths{{1cm}{1cm}{1cm}}
\brow \cell{a} \cell{bc} \cell{d} \erow
% hack displays and forgets the row separation above
\lastrule \let\cals@last@context=n
\colwidths{{1cm}{2cm}}
\brow \cell{a} \cell{bcd} \erow
\end{calstable}


\end{document}
```